# Installing npm packages globally not working

Tags: npm, webpack

I'm trying to install webpack globally, but instead, I get the following:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Andrew> npm install webpack -g
C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\npm\webpack -> C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- webpack@2.3.2

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\webpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules
\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any
"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

When I try to run webpack, I get nothing:

```
PS C:\Users\Andrew> webpack
webpack : The term 'webpack' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ webpack
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (webpack:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When I try to see my global packages, I get nothing:

```
PS C:\Users\Andrew> npm ls
C:\Users\Andrew
`-- (empty)

PS C:\Users\Andrew>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: I would guess that it's because `C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\npm` is not in your `PATH`.

Comment: then why can't I see it when I do npm ls?

Comment: Well, it should be `npm ls -g` to list globally installed packages.